# Scrabble game code with hashmaps

Tags: hashmap

I can not for the life of me figure this problem out for school. If somebody could just point me in the right direction?

Given a list of words, select the one that earns the highest score.

```
ScrabbleAssistant
+ getBestWord(List<String> options,
Map<Character, Integer> letterScores) : String
+ getScore(String word,
Map<Character, Integer> letterScores) : int
```

We will give you a list of words and a dictionary that tells you how many points each letter in the word is worth. You return the word that earned the highest score.

Answer (score 0):

I normally wouldn't do someone's homework for them, but here is the pseudo code

```
maxScore = 0
bestWord = ""
for each word
    totalScore = 0
    for each letter in word
        totaScore = total + lookup value of letter from collection
    if totalScore > maxScore  
        maxScore = totalScore
        bestWord = word
```

Comment: I'm still a little stuck, i get the pseudo code but not sure how to put this in my methods.

Comment: Pseudo code is basically the `getBestWord` method. The `foreach letter in word` loop could be taken out and turned into the `getScore` method.

Comment: Time to visit your tutor!